# Передача user_id в хэндлер pyrogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

Здравствуйте подскажите как мне можно получить айди пользователя в хэндлере?

```
@Client.on_message(filters.command(f"test_{вот сюда мне нужно передать айди}") & filters.me)
async def send8ussage(client, message):
```

Comment: Ничего не понял

Comment: Получить user_id нужно в @Client.on_message